# Exporting a Trained Inference Graph TENSERFLOW

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained my custom model and want to export a trained inference graph

I ran the following command

```
INPUT_TYPE=image_tensor
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH= training/ ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
TRAINED_CKPT_PREFIX= training/model.ckpt-2509
EXPORT_DIR= training/new_model
python exporter.py \
    --input_type=${INPUT_TYPE} \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix=${TRAINED_CKPT_PREFIX} \
    --output_directory=${EXPORT_DIR}
```

And I got the following output

```
W0819 22:08:54.649750  2680 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\Aleksej\Anaconda3\envs\cocosynth4\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\nets\mobilenet\mobilenet.py:397: The name tf.nn.avg_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.avg_pool2d instead.


(cocosynth4) D:\yolo\models\research\object_detection>    --input_type=${INPUT_TYPE} \
'--input_type' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(cocosynth4) D:\yolo\models\research\object_detection>    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
'--pipeline_config_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(cocosynth4) D:\yolo\models\research\object_detection>    --trained_checkpoint_prefix=${TRAINED_CKPT_PREFIX} \
'--trained_checkpoint_prefix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(cocosynth4) D:\yolo\models\research\object_detection>    --output_directory=${EXPORT_DIR}
'--output_directory' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am running a windows 10 and python3.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this code

python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-3970 --output_directory ships_inference_graph